# How To Set Language to Chinese Using Ajax Form Submit to A Different PHP File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, special-characters

I am working on a project with Chinese language (gb2312). We have a form that submit customer input data from File 1 to a php File 2 using Ajax. The two files display Chinese without problem. But when the same data was submitted from File 1 to File 2, it turned to be totally wrong characters. For example:

File 1

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="msg">0</div>

<form id="add-form" action="file2.php" method="POST">
<input type=text name='content' value='试试这个' >
<input type="button"  id="add-post" value="Run Code" />
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#add-post").click(function()
{
    $("#add-form").submit(function(e)
    {
        $("#msg").html("<img src='/image/progress_bar.gif'/>");
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=gb2312",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                $("#msg").html('<pre>'+data+'</pre>');
            },
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
    });

    $("#add-form").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

File 2

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $_POST['content'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Both of the files display Chinese characters without problem. But when submitting content in Chinese from File 1 to File 2 the content becomes garbled not appears to be the correct characters. I think the problem should be somewhere in the Ajax submit script but do not know how to fix it.

Would you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is definitely occurring at the Ajax request. If you look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for the `contentType` property, you will see the following note:

> The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.

You can return gb2312 characters when rendering the page for the browser, but it looks like the Ajax request will always be sent in UTF-8. You will therefore need to have your PHP script accept UTF-8 in order to get it to parse the data correctly. I suggest removing the `contentType` header from the Ajax request.

After your PHP received the UTF8-encoded string, you can convert it back into gb2312 using the [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function:

```
$chinese_content = iconv('UTF-8', 'GB2312', $_POST['content']);
```

Comment: Yes, I followed your recommendation by removing contentType header from Ajax request and have the PHP script in File 2 to accept UTF-8. The content did show correct character on File 2. But this is conflicting with our mysql database setting on File 2. The solution generated another problem for us. I wonder if there is another way to submit gb2312 content to a different file? Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to convert your UTF8 string into GB2312 which you can then use for database interaction.